# Why does this infinite loop in C not loop infinitely?

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I am running this below 'C' program which has an infinite loop. I see the CPU reaching almost 99% using the 'top' command. Then suddenly the program stops. I was curious to know what rule in the system is causing it to stop.

I am running this under a docker image alpine:3.1 (+ some modules) and I just simply start its ash (alpine's bash).
Also, I can not find ulimit.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int marks[10],i,n,sum=0;
    printf("Enter number of students: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; --i) {
        //printf("Enter marks of student%d: ",i+1);
        int c;
        c = 5;
        int a;
        a = c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what rule causes infinite loop program to stop a 'C' program ?

Comment: probably `n` has a garbage value, since you did not check the result from `scanf`.  That could be *anything*, causing an indefinite loop in the program.

Comment: Your code invokeds undefined behaviour by signed integer over/underflow. Anything can happen.

Comment: Why do you think that loop that demonstrably stops is "infinite"? ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua: Rolled back your edit, because you changed the code.

Comment: @Olaf Should be better this time...

Answer (score 12):

As you mention, you could expect this to produce an infinite loop, at least if `n` is positive.

The behaviour you're seeing instead is caused by your counter wrapping around: when it reaches `INT_MIN`, the result of `--i` is `INT_MAX` (at least, with GCC's default settings on Intel-style CPUs — this is not defined in C, see below) and `i<n` fails.

So your program uses 100% of one CPU while it counts down from 0 to `INT_MIN`, then wraps around to `INT_MAX` and stops.

You can add

```
printf("%d\n", i);
```

just before the `return` line to see the value of `i` when the loop exits.

Note that this is [undefined behaviour in C](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)... If you compile this with `-O2`, at least with GCC 5.3, the program never exits the loop, because the optimiser decides that the exit condition will never be reached, and compiles the loop as a tight infinite loop if `n` is positive (`.L4: jmp .L4`).

Comment: A signed integer is not required to wrap around, but the code invokes UB.

Comment: It does not stop because of reaching `INT_MIN`

Answer (score 3):

Your loop is not infinite per se. YOu have a termnation condition which can be reached - in principle. The CPU load occurs, just because the loop runs for (likely) >2000000000 iterations before it ends.

First of all, you don't check the result of `scanf`. If it failed, `n` is unspecified.

Worse, your code invokes *undefined behaviour* (UB) due to signed integer over-/underflow. You decrement `i` past the minimum representable `int` value `INT_MIN`. Note that C does not have arbitrary length integers like Python.

Undefined behaviour means anything can happen, all bets are off. In your case, it **might** wrap to the max. positive `int` `INT_MAX`, thus the comparison fails and the loop is exited. **But this is nothing you can rely on!**

From the text and rest of the code, you likely don't want to decrement `i`, but increment: `i++`, so it counts from `0` to `n - 1`. Note that you also should check `n` for a valid range and ask the use to enter a valid value again. For the example, a negative upper limit is useless (but it does also no harm).